# how can we send a message to particular WebSocket connection from server side

Tags: java, java-websocket

how can we send a message to particular WebSocket connection.

Comment: What country do you want to show?  Have you tried the using the geocoder to initialize your map?  [example that uses the geocoder to zoom to countries](http://geocodezip.com/v3_zoom2countrySelectList.html)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Read this first http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: You should create a new question instead completely editing an old one. And what is exactly your question? What is the particular websocket connection? Is your message a text message? Are you using Tyrus implementation or Spring or something else?